# Stopped to get Post ID in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I generated wordpress post through array and WP function wp_insert_post

Same code stopped to generate Post ID without any error. Post gets created perfectly.

```
$my_post_data = array(
'post_title' => $title,
'post_content' => $part1.'</p></p>',
'post_category' => array(7),
'post_status' => 'draft'
```

);

It is not complex at all even then post creation is not returning ID

```
    $post_id=wp_insert_post($my_post_data,1);
    echo $post_id;
```

I was doing further processing based on $post_id so it is vital to get $post_id properly

Comment: Did you try,setting with `wp_error` as 0

Comment: @Shan yes, it was without wp_error first which is default. I made it 1 to see if any error is generated but it is not generating errors. Post is also created, it is not returning any post_id

Comment: Can you post the $my_post_data array

Comment: @Shan Arry posted in original Q now. In next 3 attempts, all 3 times post was created and **once** it displayed post id !!, means the code probably do not need any modifications but there maybe some server related issue